# Java: Framework for thread shared data

Tags: java, multithreading, thread-safety

I've written a few multithreaded hobby programs and some in my previous(engineering/physics) studies as well, so I consider myself to have an above-beginner knowledge in the area of synchronization/thread safety and primitives, what the average user finds to be challanging with the JMM and multiple threads etc.

What I find that I need and there is no proper method of marking instance or static members of classes as shared by different threads. Think about it, we have access rules such as private/protected/public and conventions on how to name getters/setters and a lot of things.

But what about threading? What if I want to mark a variable as thread shared and have it follow certain rules? Volatile/Atomic refs might do the job, but sometimes you just do need to use mutexes. And when you manually have to remember to use something...you will forget about it :) - At some point.

So I had an idea, and I see I am not the first, I also checked out http://checkthread.org/example-threadsafe.html - They seem to have a pretty decent code analyzer which I might try later which sort of lets me do some of the things I want.

But coming back to the initial problem. Let's say we need something a little more low level than a message passing framework and we need something a little more high level than primitive mutexes... What do we have...wel...nothing?

So basically, what I've made is a sort of pure java super-simple framework for threading that lets you declare class members as shared or non-shared...well sort of :).

Below is an example of how it could be used:

```
public class SimClient extends AbstractLooper {

    private static final int DEFAULT_HEARTBEAT_TIMEOUT_MILLIS = 2000;
    // Accessed by single threads only
    private final SocketAddress socketAddress;
    private final Parser parser;
    private final Callback cb;
    private final Heart heart;
    private boolean lookingForFirstMsg = true;
    private BufferedInputStream is;
    // May be accessed by several threads (T*)  
    private final Shared<AllThreadsVars> shared = new Shared<>(new AllThreadsVars());

.
.
.
.

    static class AllThreadsVars {

        public boolean connected = false;
        public Socket socket = new Socket();
        public BufferedOutputStream os = null;
        public long lastMessageAt = 0;
    }
```

And to access the variables marked as thread shared you must send a runnable-like functor to the Shared object:

```
public final void transmit(final byte[] data) {
    shared.run(new SharedRunnable<AllThreadsVars, Object, Object>() {

        @Override
        public Object run(final AllThreadsVars sharedVariable, final Object input) {
            try {
                if (sharedVariable.socket.isConnected() && sharedVariable.os != null) {
                    sharedVariable.os.write(data);
                    sharedVariable.os.flush();
                }
            } catch (final Exception e) { // Disconnected
                setLastMessageAt(0);
            }
            return null;
        }
    }, null);
}
```

Where a shared runnable is defined like:

```
public interface SharedRunnable<SHARED_TYPE, INPUT, OUTPUT> {
    OUTPUT run(final SHARED_TYPE s, final INPUT input);
}
```

Where is this going?
Well this gives me the help (yes you can leak out and break it but far less likely) that I can mark variable sets (not just variables) as thread shared, and once that is done, have it guaranteed in compile time ( I cannot *forget* to synchronize some method). It also allows me to standardize and perform tests to look for possible deadlocks also in compile time (Though atm I only implemented it in runtime cause doing it in compile time with the above framework will probably require more than just the java compiler).

Basically this is extremely useful to me and I'm wondering if I'm just reinventing the wheel here or of this could be some anti-pattern I don't know of. And I really don't know who to ask. (Oh yeah and *Shared*.run(*SharedRunnable* r, *INPUT* input) works just like

```
private final <OUTPUT, INPUT> OUTPUT run(final SharedRunnable<SHARED_TYPE, INPUT, OUTPUT> r, final INPUT input) { 
    try {
        lock.lock();
        return r.run(sharedVariable, input);
    } finally {
        lock.unlock();
    }
}
```

This is just my own experimentation so it's not really finished by any means, but I have one decent project using it right now and it's really helping out a lot.

Comment: I don't think I understood your example, but **shared variables** is exactly what you **don't want to have** when dealing with concurrency. Shared variables with locks will make you move slower, waste more time waiting for locks, be less responsive in general and fall into deadlocks. The best way to reach real concurrency is by having no shared state at all.

Comment: Yes but at some point in your application, if it requires multiple threads, it will require some shared variable, whether it's a message queue or something else. What my idea is, is to have a way to construct arbitrary atomic-like operations (and important: Enforcing the use of them in compile-time on Shared-marked states). Also I could without too much effort write a deadlock analysis tool for this, since all my threads use a standardized framework. I wrote a rather simplified variant of that already, and could detect some potential deadlock places in my code.

Comment: Personally, I'd use what is given in the java.util.concurrent packages before I'd resort to this.

Comment: If I can find something useful there, absolutely :). So far I haven't been able to for this specific application, but maybe I will. I use them for a lot of other purposes though.

Answer (score 4):

You mean something like [this](http://www.javaconcurrencyinpractice.com/annotations/doc/net/jcip/annotations/package-summary.html)?  (which can be enforced by tools like [findbugs](http://findbugs.sourceforge.net/manual/annotations.html).)

Comment: Yes, something like that, thank you. Using my own I do not need to have a code analysis tool to do it, the compiler is enough, though net.jcip.annotations looks very nice :). I will have to read up on how its contracts work before I can decide if to use that or my own code.

Answer (score 0):

If you have values which should be shared, the best approach is encapsulate this within the class.  This way the caller does need to know what thread model you are using.  If you want to know what model is used internally, you can read the source, however the caller cannot forget to access a ConcurrentMap (for example) correctly because all its method are thread safe.

Comment: The problem is that somtimes more things need to be done synchronized than just adding/removing from a predefined synchronized collection. Let's say you have your map, a flag and a timestamp.
    public void foo() {
        if (flag == ...) {
             modify(map);
             setTimeStamp();
             flag = newValue;
        }
    }
My idea here is to encapsulate all these shared variables and that entire operation as synchronized. And to enforce the synchronization, so I dont forget to do it, even in the encapsulating class. A synchronized method is not enough, you could forget.

Comment: Also what if yuo implement new behaviour of the encapsulating class, or exend it, it is super easy to forget to keep the thread safe behaviour, unless it is somehow enforced at compile time. I am not saying my solution is the best, far from it, but seeing as it has (see jtahlborn and checkthread) been done before in a very similar manner, I don't think it's entirely wrong. Still, I may try to redesign my application so I don't need this stuff. Message passing is probably better after all. Thanks for all input from everyone. I need to figure out how to close this question now :).

Comment: If you have a component which uses many other component which all has to be in a thread safe manner you can still use encapsulation to centrally manage all the synchronization requirements.  This simplifies maintaining your code. Exposing your locking is more powerful but dangerous which is why many of the concurrency libraries deliberately hide this locking.